# Work with Twitter upload, update_with_media API and curl

Tags: php, api, twitter, curl, upload

I want to update twitter status with a "photo URL".

Here is my code:

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json');
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);


curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('media'=> '@http://sample.com/image.jpg', 'status'=>'This is a test image!'));
//'media' =>'@http://sample.com/image.jpg;type=image/jpeg;filename=image.jpg' doesn't work, too

$response = curl_exec($ci);
```

I also try using apigee but not successful [click here to test it!](https://apigee.com/console/twitter?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22statuses_update_with_media%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22media%22%3A%22%40https%3A%2F%2Fapigee.com%2Fimages%2Fapigee_logo.png%22%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%22Content-Type%22%3A%22multipart%2Fform-data%22%2C%22User-Agent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.1%29%20AppleWebKit%2F535.19%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F18.0.1025.162%20Safari%2F535.19%22%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22requestBody%22%3A%22null%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22post%22%7D)

PS: I don't want to use tmhOAuth class!

Comment: i am looking for the same thing, did you find a solution?

Comment: Any solutions to this?  I see that it's quite old and still unanswered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

I forced to use a pre-made library just for image upload:
https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

You can seed it with authentication variables. You can still use your own code for other API requests if you really want.